# Parse platform android add/put seperate rows instead of row of arrays

Tags: java, android, database, parse-platform

I'm having issues with Parse platform with android. When NutrientID uploads (see add below), its making an array of rows instead of a new row for every item thats added.

```
ParseObject a6 = new ParseObject("c5");
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bufferedInputStream));

 try {
      String line;
      int iteration = 0;
      String [] nextLine;
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (iteration == 0) {
          iteration++;
          continue;
        }
        String[] cols = line.split(",");
        a6.add("NutrientID", cols[0]); 
}
a6.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
          @Override
          public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
              Log.i("Parse", "Success");
            } else {
              Log.i("parse", e.toString());
            }
          }
        });
 } catch (IOException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
 ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
  }
}
```

[row of arrays image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxqUQ.png)

EDIT: Sample data is at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V0Gihnhs82d5rhj6Bun1m_UNOYKnAIKt/view?usp=sharing

[simple example of put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ3uY.png)

Comment: Please post the object you are parsing

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. "c5" is the object in parse? or do you want sample data which is called filename?

Comment: I added sample data.

Comment: What is ParseObject class? Can you provide  link? And what is c5?

Comment: c5 could be anything, its arbitrary. https://parseplatform.org/

Comment: I don't think you are doing correctly. Documentation says this about add method,

**add(java.lang.String key, java.lang.Object value)
Atomically adds an object to the end of the array associated with a given key.**

Comment: I've used both put and add and both dont work as I would like

Comment: What happens with put? Can you show?

Comment: if I do a simple example, such as a6.put("test1", 123);
a6.put("test1", 555); it only shows 555 in the database, it ignores/deletes/overwrites the 123 value

Comment: I am asking like image you provided after doing add, can you provide the image with what is created when you do put?

Comment: updated initial post for screenshot of puts